# How to get a UK work visa to work remotely for a US company?

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa

I’m working for a small remote tech company that is not on the UK registered sponsors list (being a US company). We have one employee who works in the UK and has “settlement” (permanent residence) there. I’m a software developer and my salary and job requirements qualify me as RQF 6 (fits the “skilled labor” criteria).

I work remotely right now in the US (I’m a US born citizen), but I’d like to work in the UK to be able to work with our employee there when needed, and for other numerous reasons.

Is there a way for me to get some kind of a work visa to do this? I’ve looked pretty hard but haven’t found something yet and was wondering if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to work with the UK person full time? I don't think there is a way to do that, but you can use the standard visit visa for intra-corporate activities on an intermittent basis.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules#visitors-appendix-3-permitted-activities-for-all-visitors